# Testing for all of the possible values of a constant

Tags: c#, unit-testing, constants, mstest

I have a constant in my application which determines the operation of some other parts of the program. I change this constant to quickly and easily alter the operation of the program.

In my case, the constant is a `bool` so it can have one of two values.

I want to write a test that will make sure my code is working whether the constant is set to true or not.

For example, say my method is this:

```
public boolean IsEqual(float a, float b) {
    var epsilon = 0.0001;

    if (Constants.Exact) return (Math.Abs(a-b) < epsilon);
    else return (Math.Floor(a) == Math.Floor(b)); 
}
```

`Constants` looks like this:

```
public static class Constants {
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether an exact comparison should be made, or whether fractional parts should be disregarded.
    /// </summary>
    public const bool Exact = true;
}
```

And the test method is:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestEquality() {
    var five = 5;
    var three = 3;

    Assert.True(Equals(five, three));
}
```

Solutions I could come up with:

- Write the test as if the constant doesn't exist, set the constant to `true` and run tests, then set it to false and run tests. Bad because if I have 8 constants like this, I don't want to run the tests 256 times.
- Don't make it a constant. Inside the test method, first set constant to true, assert, then false, assert again. However, the reason I made it a constant in the first place is so that it's guaranteed not to change at run-time.

I guess what I really want is a way to make it constant as far as the application proper is concerned, but not a constant as far as the test project is concerned.

So how can I make a situation like this work?

Comment: I know this is not what you're asking, but comparing floating point numbers using == is rarely a good idea. Why do you want to enable this?

Comment: You could make it static with an `internal` setter, then you just need to be sure that you don't change it within that project (or within projects that you expose it to via `InternalsVisibleTo`)

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Edited to add epsilon comparison, but it's just a simple example. I'm not actually comparing floats.

Comment: You probably should use a `static readonly` field rather than a `const` if you're going to be changing it. "Constants are forever."

Comment: @JimMischel `readonly` fields can only be assigned to by constructors. Since test methods are not constructors, how would that allow me to set `Constants.Exact` from within the test method?

Comment: @Superbest: Just replace `public const bool Exact = true;` in your `Constants` class with `public static readonly bool Exact = true;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two overloads of the function, one with an additional `exact` parameter and one using the `Exact` constant implicitly

```
public bool IsEqual(float a, float b)
{
    return IsEqual(a, b, Constants.Exact);
}

public bool IsEqual(float a, float b, bool exact)
{
    if (exact)
        return a == b;
    else
        return Math.Floor(a) == Math.Floor(b);
}
```

Now you can test for any value of `excat` without relying on a predefined constant.

---

**UPDATE** using `IEquatable<float>` (see comments)

`IEquatable<T>.Equals` has only one parameter. Therefore I assume that the other value is defined as property `Value` in this example

```
public float Value { get; set; }

#region IEquatable<float> Members

public bool Equals(float other)
{
    return Equals(other, Constants.Exact);
}

#endregion

public bool Equals(float other, bool exact)
{
    if (exact)
        return Value == other;
    else
        return Math.Floor(Value) == Math.Floor(other);
}
```

Comment: You can do that, even if the method is called `Equals` and implements `IEquatable<T>.Equals`. With the overload you simply have an additional method that is not implementing the interface. I don't see any problems with it.

Comment: Yes, I later realized that it doesn't affect inheritance, so I deleted the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could create the constant internally and represent it through a property, so you say

```
   private const bool _exact = false;

   public bool Exact 
   {  
     get { return _exact };
     set { throw new Exception("Don't set this, you crazy donkey") };
   }
```

Then for testing you could create a class that inherits from your constant class but overrides the `Exact` property. As long as you call it by it's public-facing name within the parent class then you should be able to vary the value in test and keep it constant in your regular implementation.

Edit: In fact if your constants are all defined in a single class then the best way to work it is to simply extract the interface from that class, then you can switch implementation at test time ( or any other if you're using a DI framework of some kind ) or simply use a mocking framework to mock out whatever parts you need for a given test.

Comment: So if in my test project I declare an override for `Exact` with a working setter, won't this fail to do anything because the `IsEqual` method explicitly references the `Exact` in the `Constants` class, not the one in the test class?

Comment: Yes, of course you are right, you would need to do this in the Constants class, not the one using the properties.

Answer (score 0):

Use an enumeration instead of a constant. That way you prevent it from being changed to something unexpected, yet it is modifiable and can scale with more values.

Comment: An Enum variable can be set to values other than those in the enumeration definition; it's only a thin veneer around the backing type (typically int).  You can perform `var x = (MyEnum)-1235412;`, for instance.

Comment: I'd argue it's better than changing a constant though.